# Contenteditable - Editing <code> element is inconsistent in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I have a WYSIWYG Editor using contenteditable that allows users to insert "code snippets" using a `<code>` element.  For instance:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>
        This is a paragraph with an <code>inline snippet</code>!
    </p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wyeack/pyta77zd/2/

In firefox, if you place the caret directly before the first character of `<code>`, it will prepend the element:

[image]
[image]

However, if you try to do the same thing in Chrome, it appends it to the previous element:
[image]

This means that if you use chrome, there is no way of adding content to the beginning of this element.

What's going on here?  Is there a way for me to make the behavior more consistent?

Comment: Contenteditable remains inconsistent between browsers (and I'm not sure that you can do much about it). Firefox has become a bit out-of-step with other major browsers. Chrome and IE(9+, I think) behave the same way - you can add to the end of your inline element but not the beginning. (Spans are affected the same way). A possible answer in your case is to put a space at the start of your <code> section - if people click after the space it will be included in the code section - but this is well iffy...

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a superior selection implementation in this case. You can place it inside an inline element like `<code>` if you move it from right to left using arrow keys. If you move it from left to right, it will stick to the left. This is, so called, gravity.

> What's going on here? Is there a way for me to make the behavior more consistent?

First of all – don't use bare `contentEditable`. Use a good RTE.

Second (and last :P) of all – I don't know about any RTE which normalises this specific behaviour. It's an expensive thing to do and few users would notice it. It is possible, though, but you would need to use an RTE with a proper data model (where the selection is fully abstracted and all input intercepted) and based on that handle the input accordingly.

I could give you more details on how to do it with [CKEditor 5](https://ckeditor5.github.io), but it's not production ready yet. I've got no idea how to do that with other RTEs, but I know one thing for sure – I'd never ever attempted to fix this on a native `contentEditable`.

Comment: I am building a WYSIWYG editor using DevExpress' HTMLEditor RTE - the JSFiddle I posted was just meant to illustrate the issue.  Unfortunately, DevExpress' editor doesn't normalize this either :(

Comment: I actually am not sure how I could even do this if I was intercepting all input - I use rangy.js and when the caret is at the beginning of a code element, rangy also seems to think that it is at the end of the previous element rather than the start of the code element...